# Is it possible to display emails instead of tokens in User Pool in AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to display emails instead of tokens in User Pool in AWS Console?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It is possible however to request them via the AWS CLI/AWS SDK. But for now, in the console, only the field username is shown.